# unique_ptr assigning to nullptr in own function

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, destructor, unique-ptr

In below code , In function makenull , when I deference the own unique_ptr then destructor of object is invoked that's fine. Now even after destructor is completed how can makenull function still getting executed and printed "after null" why not segmentation fault exception came?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class X{
    public:
    ~X(){
        
        cout<<"In destructor of X\n";
        
    }
    
    void makenull(std::unique_ptr<X> ptr){
        cout<<"before null\n";
    ptr = nullptr;
    cout<<"after null\n";
        
    }
    
    
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World\n";
    std::unique_ptr<X> x = std::make_unique<X>();
    x->makenull(std::move(x));
    cout<<"In main......";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially like doing `aoto x = new X;` and then calling a member function that does `delete this;`. And there are many duplicates of that if you search a little.

Comment: After the `ptr = nullptr;` the code is skating on thin ice.  Since no member variables are accessed, and the now invalid `this` is not used, it narrowly avoids undefined behavior.

Comment: And honestly, if you know you're doing something which could be bad, just don't do it.

Comment: where is member function code stored, once members are destroyed isn't runtime remove the function from memory also?

Answer (score 1):

> why not segmentation fault exception came?

In case of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the code it's literally not defined what the behavior of the code should be, you cannot "expect" any outcome from the code.

[Segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is a signal that your operating system sends to the process in case your programs tries to access, read or write, to a memory location it is not allowed to. Because during the execution your program did no such thing, so your program did not receive a segmentation fault. Ie. you can't "expect" that freeing the object memory in mids of that objects member function execution, which is undefined behavior, will result in segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `X` is to trivial. It doesn't have any fields or virtual methods so as a result pointer `this` is never used.

So when you destroy object while its method is executed nothing bad happens since no operation is performed on this piece of memory.

Comment: what if X has member and used before ptr=nullptr; like
class X{
int b;
~X(){...}
 void makenull(std::unique_ptr<X> ptr){
        cout<<"before null"<<b;
    ptr = nullptr;
    cout<<"after null\n";
        
    }
}

Comment: then you have undefined behavior (currently you have not), so anything can happen.